# I am not able submit the form django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-3.1

RuntimeError at /home
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/home/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/home/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py, line 87, in get_full_path_with_slash
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Deepak\protfolio',
'C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
'C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
'C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
'C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages',
'C:\Users\Deepak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 16 Jan 2021 06:27:38 +0000

Comment: Please style your code accordingly https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that your form was posted to `/home` But it could not find /home in URL patterns. Change the POST URL in your template.
Also, check [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) which mentions that data loss could happen for forms when Django tries to redirect.

> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the
> patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP
> redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that
> the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be
> lost.